# Can't see a heatmap using Heatma.ps SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, heatmap, heatma.ps

I successfully installed **heatma.ps SDK** (https://heatma.ps) in my iPhone application. It tracks all the touches and gestures, but I can't view a heatmap when I shake my device. Any idea why? There is no log, it just doesn't show up.

This is how I setup my `heatmaps` object.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    heatmaps = [[Heatmaps alloc] init];
    heatmaps.showDebug = YES;
    [heatmaps start];

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see heatmaps you need to set `showMenu` property of `heatmaps` object to `YES`

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    heatmaps = [[Heatmaps alloc] init];
    heatmaps.showDebug = YES;

    heatmaps.showMenu = YES;

    [heatmaps start];

    //...
}
```

Watch the following screencast: ["Viewing heatmaps"](https://heatma.ps/support/getting-started/viewing-heatmaps/)